Volume of Bluetooth devices isn't saved across sessions
Issue
I run Linux Mint on my Satellite P55W-C laptop, and what I've observed was that the Bluetooth volume for my ear buds starts at 80% whenever I connect to this Bluetooth device after closing and reopening the laptop. Even after I adjust it to 30-40% it goes back to 80% after I restart the laptop. This kind of problem persisted across multiple distros like Debian, Ubuntu, Arch which I have used in the past on the same laptop. This issue did not occur in the Windows OS I dual boot in it.
Specifications
Laptop:
OS: Linux Mint 21.3 x86_64
Host: Satellite P55W-C PSPVJU-00T016B
Kernel: 5.15.0-112-generic
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: Cinnamon 6.0.4
WM: Mutter (Muffin)
Terminal: gnome-terminal
Earbuds: OnePlus Nord Buds 2
Question
Is there a way to enable saving the Bluetooth volume levels of Bluetooth devices across multiple sessions?
